# Rabbitmq beam.smp 100%

Tags: python, python-2.7, rabbitmq, amqp, pika

I have around 4 million messages queued up across 2 queues in rabbitmq,  I have written a consumer in python that consumes these 2 queues,  when I run the consumer to read from the queue the CPU usage seems to spike up to around 124% CPU.  Another problem I am facing is that the rate at which my consumer is getting the messages is significantly higher than the rate I am acknowledging.  After a short while, the consumers just drop off according to rabbitmq management.  What I mean by that is they stop working altogether.  Here is the code I have written to consume from a queue

```
class MetConsumer(Consumer):
    print 'Metrics consumer started...'

    def handle_payload(self, channel, method, properties, body):
        print "met"
        jsonItem = json.loads(body)
        type = jsonItem['type']
        data = jsonItem['data']
        print json.dumps(data)
        self.medium.server.invoke('Send', method.delivery_tag, type, json.dumps(data))
        channel.basic_ack(method.delivery_tag)
```

As you can see I try to acknowledge the message as soon as it is sent.  I am getting 4000 messages a second, but only acknowledging around 20 a second